# How to Save Record Video in SharpAvi

Tags: c#

I would like to record screen video then save as Mp4,Webm or any video format.
I am using SharpAvi to record video,The code below is recording video but I am unable to save after stop ,Please help Here is my code.

```
 namespace RecordScreenvideo
 {
// Used to Configure the Recorder
public class RecorderParams
{
    public RecorderParams(string filename, int FrameRate, FourCC Encoder, int Quality)
    {
        FileName = filename;
        FramesPerSecond = FrameRate;
        Codec = Encoder;
        this.Quality = Quality;

        Height = (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        Width = (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    }

    string FileName;
    public int FramesPerSecond, Quality;
    FourCC Codec;

    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public AviWriter CreateAviWriter()
    {
        return new AviWriter(FileName)
        {
            FramesPerSecond = FramesPerSecond,
            EmitIndex1 = true,
        };
    }

    public IAviVideoStream CreateVideoStream(AviWriter writer)
    {
        // Select encoder type based on FOURCC of codec
        if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed) return writer.AddUncompressedVideoStream(Width, Height);
        else if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg) return writer.AddMotionJpegVideoStream(Width, Height, Quality);
        else
        {
            return writer.AddMpeg4VideoStream(Width, Height, (double)writer.FramesPerSecond,
                // It seems that all tested MPEG-4 VfW codecs ignore the quality affecting parameters passed through VfW API
                // They only respect the settings from their own configuration dialogs, and Mpeg4VideoEncoder currently has no support for this
                quality: Quality,
                codec: Codec,
                // Most of VfW codecs expect single-threaded use, so we wrap this encoder to special wrapper
                // Thus all calls to the encoder (including its instantiation) will be invoked on a single thread although encoding (and writing) is performed asynchronously
                forceSingleThreadedAccess: true);
        }
    }
}
public class Recorder : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields
    AviWriter writer;
    RecorderParams Params;
    IAviVideoStream videoStream;
    Thread screenThread;
    ManualResetEvent stopThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    #endregion

    public Recorder(RecorderParams Params)
    {
        this.Params = Params;

        // Create AVI writer and specify FPS
        writer = Params.CreateAviWriter();

        // Create video stream
        videoStream = Params.CreateVideoStream(writer);
        // Set only name. Other properties were when creating stream, 
        // either explicitly by arguments or implicitly by the encoder used
        videoStream.Name = "Captura";

        screenThread = new Thread(RecordScreen)
        {
            Name = typeof(Recorder).Name + ".RecordScreen",
            IsBackground = true
        };

        screenThread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stopThread.Set();
        screenThread.Join();

        // Close writer: the remaining data is written to a file and file is closed
        writer.Close();

        stopThread.Dispose();
    }

    void RecordScreen()
    {
        var frameInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / (double)writer.FramesPerSecond);
        var buffer = new byte[Params.Width * Params.Height * 4];
        Task videoWriteTask = null;
        var timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;

        while (!stopThread.WaitOne(timeTillNextFrame))
        {
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

            Screenshot(buffer);

            // Wait for the previous frame is written
            videoWriteTask?.Wait();

            // Start asynchronous (encoding and) writing of the new frame
            videoWriteTask = videoStream.WriteFrameAsync(true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            timeTillNextFrame = timestamp + frameInterval - DateTime.Now;
            if (timeTillNextFrame < TimeSpan.Zero)
                timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        // Wait for the last frame is written
        videoWriteTask?.Wait();
    }

    public void Screenshot(byte[] Buffer)
    {
        using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.Width, Params.Height))
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(Params.Width, Params.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                g.Flush();

                var bits = BMP.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.Width, Params.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                BMP.UnlockBits(bits);
            }
        }
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FourCC selectedCodec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg;


        RecorderParams recparams = new RecorderParams("recordvideo",49,selectedCodec,100);

        Recorder record = new Recorder(recparams);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to save output as mp4 or any format as you can see the method`receiving file name as first argument

```
 RecorderParams recparams = new RecorderParams("recordvideo",49,selectedCodec,100);`
```

So you need to just pass your output file path as

```
   RecorderParams recparams = new RecorderParams("D:\\recordvideo.mp4",49,selectedCodec,100);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the dispose method
so after you start recording you either need to hard-code how much time you want it to record or make it after you press any key, here is an example of main that will start record when you press any key then it will stop recording after you press any key.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FourCC selectedCodec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg;
    RecorderParams recparams = new RecorderParams("recordvideo",49,selectedCodec,100);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start recording ");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Recorder record = new Recorder(recparams);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop recording ");
    Console.ReadKey();
    record.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: Ok but this does not save the output file how to save recorded file?

Comment: this does save the file. If you go to the project directory, just make sure you use a supported Codecs. Exmp: 
` var rec = new Recorder(new RecorderParams("recordedvideo", 10, SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg, 100)); `